# Win API, get window list without using callback

Tags: windows, winapi, callback, thread-safety

This is a Windows 32 API question:
**How to get the list of windows without using callback (called by EnumWindows)?** Because I need to get the full list of windows before doing other codes which rely on this list of windows.

Comment: What's the problem with using the `EnumWindows` callback?

Comment: i'm afraid it opens a new thread so the code right after it is executed immediately

Comment: or it blocks when enumerating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnumWindows blocks the current thread, so all other codes which rely on the results of EnumWindows work fine.